# how can i auto play a video in my app using wkwebview

Tags: ios, video, ios8, autoplay

I am using `wkwebview` to show my site. and my site have a video. when the site is showed,the video cannot autoplay.is this any method to let video auto play?

Comment: yourWebView.configuration.requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback = NO;
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebViewConfiguration_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/WKWebViewConfiguration/requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback

Comment: i have this code .but it not work.

Comment: my app worked on a ipad.the ios is8.3.

Comment: Hi, same here using wkwebview, it's not working. How did you solve the issue in the end? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `function` worked for me for giving support of `auto play`

```
- (void)loadwebViewToPlay {

    NSString * videoHtml = @"<html><head><style>body{margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}</style></head> <body> <div id=\"player\"></div> <script> var tag = document.createElement('script'); tag.src = 'http://www.youtube.com/player_api'; var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); var player; function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { player = new YT.Player('player', { width:'200', height:'200', videoId:'bHQqvYy5KYo', events: { 'onReady': onPlayerReady } }); } function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); } </script> </body> </html>";

    UIWebView * webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    webview.opaque = NO;
    //videoView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:webview];
    webview.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;

    [webview loadHTMLString:videoHtml baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];

}
```

For more help you can reference [iframe_api_reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) **OR**  [player_parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

Comment: thanks. 
yourWebView.configuration.requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback = NO; is right.

Comment: But wasn't the question about WKWebView instead of UIWebView?

Answer (score 0):

Only use mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback for ios 9.0, 10.0
referent: 
@property (nonatomic) BOOL requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback", ios(9.0, 10.0));